# Initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError

Tags: ruby, sockets, https, scp

I ve downloading cookbooks from object storage which has link https,

require 'open-uri'
open("/home/admini/Desktop/apache2.tgz","wb") do |write_file|
  open("https://region-a.geo-1.objects.hpcloudsvc.com:443/v1/68342917034742/cookbooks/marketplace/production/apache2.tar","rb") do |read_file|
     write_file.write(read_file.read)
  end
end

it gets downloads for some providers but for some providers it doesnot get downloads ,showing like this:

from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in`block in connect'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in`timeout'

I ve tried using resolv-replace gem also ,but didinot solve yet,any idea guys?
Is there any built in library method  for supporting https in ruby? or we have to use gem only?

Regards,
indu

Answer (score -1):

Try this library https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#streaming-the-response-body it's pretty awesome, supports redirects (https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#following-redirections), can do parallel downloads etc.